# Entries relation

Tags: entries, relations, field, entries-field

I have two entries, let's say A and B. In the B entry I can select multiple A entries in a entries field. I want to get B entries that have specific A entries selected. So i have the code:

```
{% set entriesAArray = [1,2,3] %}
{% set entriesB = craft.entries.section('B').relatedTo(A) %}
```

`entriesAArray` - I have the ids of the A entries that I want the B entries to have selected in the entries field.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you just want to select all entries in section B where a custom entries field has entries 1, 2 and 3 from section A selected?